# MultiValueDictKeyError at /search

Tags: html, django

I'm trying to add an object to my user's profile but when I post the form I get the error:

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /search
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

I am not sure if the issue is related to me having two functions posting a form in the same view or if something else is going on but either way I would like to fix it.

These are the views related to it and the one that I'm trying to get to work is the 'anime' view:

```
def search(request):
    animes = []

    if request.method == 'POST':
        animes_url = 'https://api.jikan.moe/v3/search/anime?q={}&limit=6&page=1'
        
        search_params = {
            'animes' : 'title',
            'q' : request.POST['search']
            
            }

        r = requests.get(animes_url, params=search_params)
        results = r.json()
        
        results = results['results']
        
        
        if len(results):
            for result in results:
                animes_data = {
                    'Id' : result["mal_id"],
                    'Title' : result["title"],
                    'Episodes' : result["episodes"],
                    'Image' : result["image_url"]
                }
                animes.append(animes_data)
        else:
            message = print("No results found")

        for item in animes:
            print(item)
     
    context = {
    'animes' : animes
    }
        
    return render(request,'search.html', context)

def anime(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        anime_id = request.POST.get("anime_id")
        anime = Anime.objects.get(id = anime_id)
        request.user.profile.animes.add(anime)
        messages.success(request,(f'{anime} added to wishlist.'))
        return redirect ('/search')
    animes = Anime.objects.all()
    
    return render(request = request, template_name="search.html")
```

This is the html part:

```
<body>
  

  <div class = "container">
    <div class = "text-center container">
      <br>
      <h2 class = "text-center">Search for your favorite animes</h2> 
      <br>
      <form action='search' method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..." class = "text-center">
        <button type="submit" class = "btn-danger btn-sm">Search</button>

    </div> 
    </form>
    
 {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {% if animes %}
    {% for anime in animes %}
    <form method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <section>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
          <div class="card">
            
            <div class="card-body text-center">
              <p class="card-title"> <b>{{anime.Title}}</b></p>
              <hr>
              <p class="card-text">Episodes: <b>{{anime.Episodes}}</b></p>
              
              <img src = {{anime.Image}} />
              
            </div>
      </section>
      <input type="hidden" value="{{anime.Id}}" name="anime_id">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" style="font-size:18px; border-radius: 50%">★</button>
                                        
    </form>

        
        
    </div>
      
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
  {% endblock %}
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That exception means you attempted to reference a key in a MultiValueDict (`request.POST` in this case) that does not exist. Specifically in this block:

```
    search_params = {
        'animes' : 'title',
        'q' : request.POST['search']
        }
```

So the `'search'` key is not in your request data.

When you submit an HTML form, only the controls within that form are included. You have one search form and one form per `anime` object. If you submit any of those forms other than the search form, the search input will not be included. Your code doesn't account for that situation, resulting in this exception.